# application of permutation in arranging numbers

Tags: permutations

How many numbers can be formed with the digits 3,4,5,6,7 which are greater than 1000(repetition is not allowed) ?i think 2 parts will be there.first from 1000 to 9999.next from 10000 and above.i could not get the correct answer

Comment: $\binom{5}{4}4!+5!=2\cdot5!=240$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

**Case 1**: $n=\overline{abcd}$

Because every digit in $\{3,4,5,6,7\}$ is $>1$, we can select $\binom{5}{4}=5$ $4-$tuples. Each tuple can be ordened in $4!=24$ ways.

**Case 2**: $n=\overline{abcde}$

Here we have $5!=120$ numbers.

Total of cases: $5\times 24+120=240$ numbers.